# How to remove or update certain row in ObservableList

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I have a problem about detect and remove and update certain row in a list by using single element.
If I only know a single element "Corn", how do I remove it from this list.

And if I want to update all products that price is 1.49 to 2.49, also how to do it.

```
    ObservableList<Product> products = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    products.add(new Product("Laptop", 859.00, 20));
    products.add(new Product("Bouncy Ball", 2.49, 198));
    products.add(new Product("Toilet", 9.99, 74));
    products.add(new Product("The Notebook DVD", 19.99, 12));
    products.add(new Product("Corn", 1.49, 856));
    products.add(new Product("Chips", 1.49, 100));

    if (products.contains("Corn")){  
        System.out.println("True");
    }
    else System.out.println("False");


class Product {
    Product(String name, Double price, Integer quantity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    private String name;
    private Double price;
    private Integer quantity;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: ...you could use a for loop and find the product with those certain values? observable lists work the same as normal lists.

Comment: maybe this help, http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Java 8's functional types for concise, readable code:

```
products.removeIf(product -> product.name.equals("Corn"));

products.forEach(product -> {
        if (product.price == 1.49) product.price = 2.49;
});
```

If you want to retrieve all products with a certain condition, do:

```
products.stream().filter(product -> /* some condition */).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Additionally, you can simple use a normal `Iterator`:

```
for (Iterator<Product> i = products.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    Product product = i.next();
    if (product.name.equals("Corn")) i.remove();
    else if (product.price == 1.49) product.price = 2.49;
}
```

As per *Effective Java*, try to limit scope of variables as far as you can - avoid declaring iterators outside of loops.

You can't use a for-each loop here as removing within a for-each loop will result in a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a normal [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) for this. You will also need to create [getters and setters](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm).

```
for (Iterator i = products.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
    Product p = i.next();

    if (p.getName().equals("Corn")) {
        i.remove();
    } else if (p.getPrice() == 1.49) {
        p.setPrice(2.49);
    }
}
```